# how to automatically check a checkbox from a select

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, checkbox

I have two tables, the first is called [dettaglioMateriale]
[tbl dettaglioMateriale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwH1m.jpg)

the second is called [fuoriUso]
[tbl fuoriUso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MFLj.jpg)

in the first table I have a checkbox in the "Dismesso" column. I would like this Checkbox to be checked when this condition occurs:
[sql select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmcB4.jpg)

this is the checkbox in the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FU" SortExpression="Dismesso">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Dismesso") %>' Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using an update stored procedure when loading gridview data:

```
UPDATE dettaglioMateriale 
SET dettaglioMateriale.Dismesso=1 
FROM dettaglioMateriale INNER JOIN fuoriUso ON dettaglioMateriale.IDdettaglio=fuoriUso.CODdettaglio
```